# Should 'Oz' be in Quotation Marks if not Quoting Him? APA Format

Tags: characters, punctuation, apa

I am mentioning "Oz" from the "Wizard of Oz" in my APA formatted paper.  I'm not quoting him but just making a reference to his all knowingness.  Do I put Oz in quotation marks or just leave it without anything?

Comment: Is it an actual reference as in your footnotes or end notes, or are you simply mentioning him in the text?

Answer (score 11):

If you are simply referring to the character, no, don't put his name in quotes or any other special typography. Like:

> Just as the Wizard of Oz was great and powerful, so, etc.

This is true of any fictional character.

> My friend Bob is a lot like Captain Kirk, etc.

If you are quoting an actual statement from the books, then you should put it in quotes.

> Like Dorothy said, "Toto, I have a feeling we're not in Kansas any more."

If you don't give an exact quote but paraphrase, then don't use quotes.

> When I realized that the business world was not the same as college, I felt like Dorothy, when she realized that she was not in Kansas any more.

Note that the title of a book or play should be italicized or underlined.

> Just like the Wizard from *The Wizard of Oz*, so my friend Bob imagines himself to be all-powerful.